# Proteus PIC16F628A RB4 Not Working

Tags: pic, proteus, pic16f

I realized RB4 is not working. I am using Proteus 8.14. How can I fix it?

[image: RB4 Not give output]

```c
// CONFIG
#pragma config FOSC = XT        // Oscillator Selection bits (XT oscillator: Crystal/resonator on RA6/OSC2/CLKOUT and RA7/OSC1/CLKIN)
#pragma config WDTE = ON        // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT enabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = ON       // RA5/MCLR/VPP Pin Function Select bit (RA5/MCLR/VPP pin function is MCLR)
#pragma config BOREN = ON       // Brown-out Detect Enable bit (BOD enabled)
#pragma config LVP = ON         // Low-Voltage Programming Enable bit (RB4/PGM pin has PGM function, low-voltage programming enabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EE Memory Code Protection bit (Data memory code protection off)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit (Code protection off)

#include <xc.h>
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000

void main(void) 
{
    TRISB = 0x00;
    while(1)
    {
        PORTB = 0xFF;
    }
}
```

Comment: The "#pragma config LVP = ON" line indicates that RB4/PGM is set to the PGM function (I don't know PICs, but that sounds suspicious...)

Comment: @PeterBennett you know PICs better than you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the datasheet:

register 14.1 CONFIG register bit 7

> LVP: Low-Voltage Programming Enable bit
> 1 = RB4/PGM pin has PGM function, low-voltage programming enabled
> 0 = RB4/PGM is digital I/O, HV on MCL

So if you want to use RB4 as IO pin, you had to disable the LVP mode.

Comment: Thank you so much. Sometimes solution is under your eyes but you can't see :) Thank you.